# Can`t login to MsSql on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect ssms to mssql Express instance located on Azure VM. I was not able to, so I tried connecting from the VM itself.

I have tried several formats, and these are the results:

localhost\instance- works fine
internal IP \instance -works fine
sever name( without the full qualification)\instance- works fine

However

External IP\instance- not working
DNS\instance-not working

Can someone please advise? I need the DNS\IP to work

Thanks

Comment: did you configure NSG to allow traffic to external Ip on those ports?

Comment: NSG = "network security group"